# How to handle ~ in file paths

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple command line Java utility. I would like the user to be able to pass in a file path relative to their home directory using the `~` operator. So something like `~/Documents/...`

My question is is there a way to make Java resolve this type of path automatically? Or do I need to scan the file path for the `~` operator?

It seems like this type of functionality should be baked into the `File` object. But it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Which OS(s) is your utility intended for?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A simple `path = path.replaceFirst("^~", System.getProperty("user.home"));` when it is gotten from the user (before making a `File` out of it) should be enough to work in most cases - because the tilde is only expanded to a home directory if it is the first character in a directory section of a path.

Comment: Most (all?) shells would only perform the substitution when the argumetn *starts with* `~`.  The path `/a/~/c/d.txt` would be interpreted exactly as written by bash, for example.

Comment: @andrzej well then petr's solution is better however mine is a bit more compact

Comment: Just beware that this really doesn't work all the time.  "~otheruser/Documents" is a valid home directory too; but, not for "user.home", for otheruser's "user.home".  Also, the tilde is only expanded to a home directory if it is the first character in a directory section of a path.  While unconventional, "a~" is a valid file that has nothing to do with home directories.

Comment: There are a lot of `foo.bar~` files stored as backup by text editors that you probably shouldn't try to change the name of.

Comment: @Mehrdad now only replaces if first char in the string

Comment: `replaceFirst` uses regex engine where replacement can also have some special characters like `$x` to access match from group x. This means that those special characters (here `$`) need some way to be escaped and it is done with ``\`` which also makes it special character. This means that when `user.home` will represent path like `c:\foo` replacement will treat that ``\`` as special character, not as literal which will resulting in `c:foo`. To automatically escape all special characters in replacement use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("user.home"))`.

Answer (score 39):

This is shell-specific expansion, so you need to replace it at the beginning of the line, if present:

```
String path = "~/xyz";
...
if (path.startsWith("~" + File.separator)) {
    path = System.getProperty("user.home") + path.substring(1);
} else if (path.startsWith("~")) {
    // here you can implement reading homedir of other users if you care
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Home dir expansion not implemented for explicit usernames");
}

File f = new File(path);
...
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `System.getProperty("user.home") + path.substring(2);`

Comment: not really, because that would remove the separator which is typically not present in value of `user.home` and is needed to properly form the path

Answer (score 10):

As Edwin Buck pointed out in the comment to another answer, ~otheruser/Documents should also expand correctly. Here's a function that worked for me:

```
public String expandPath(String path) {
    try {
        String command = "ls -d " + path;
        Process shellExec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            new String[]{"bash", "-c", command});

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(shellExec.getInputStream()));
        String expandedPath = reader.readLine();

        // Only return a new value if expansion worked.
        // We're reading from stdin. If there was a problem, it was written
        // to stderr and our result will be null.
        if (expandedPath != null) {
            path = expandedPath;
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        // Just consider it unexpandable and return original path.
    }

    return path;
}
```

Comment: As it depends on ls, the expandPath method provided by Dave M only works if the path exists.

Comment: +1 Launching a new process for this seems like a huge overkill, but it's probably the only "correct" way.

Answer (score 5):

A fairly streamlined answer that works with paths with actual ~ characters in them:

```
String path = "~/Documents";
path.replaceFirst("^~", System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Comment: This has the same flaw as @ratchet's answer: `~foo` will be replaced by `/home/yournamefoo` instead of `/home/foo`.

Answer (score 5):

Previously mentioned solutions do not behave as expected when user home contains '\' or other special chars. This works for me:

```
path = path.replaceFirst("^~", Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```