# java getabsolute() fails for path with spaces?

Tags: java, linux

In my code, I call getAbsolutePath to get the path for my file. It works totally fine, if the file path doesnot contain any spaces. for example: ~/Desktop/data/a.txt

but I got totally wrong file path if space exists, for example ~/Desktop/data set/b.txt

Is it a bug in java? Any way to get the absolute path right with and without spaces?

code is like:

```
 public void loadDataFile(java.io.File f)
      {
          system.out.println("f.getabsolutepath is "+f.getAbsolutePath());
          ...
       }

 what I get is: 
     /home/xx/humans_d/results/a1/a.txt

 It should be:
     /home/xx/Desktop/data/hrv pilot humans_d/results/a1.a.txt
```

Thanks a lot.

LJ

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: `getAbsolutePath` doesn't understand `~` at all, whether you have spaces or not. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163364/how-to-handle-in-file-paths

Comment: new File("~/Desktop/data set/b.txt").getAbsolutePath() returns "/myWorkingDir/~/Desktop/data set/b.txt". The ~ is not replaced by the user home, with or without space. You have a problem to use the String later ?

Comment: You should firstly replace "~" with `System.getenv("HOME")`.