# Best way to process command line file path argument in Java

Tags: java, file, command-line-arguments

I'd like to pass a file path argument to my application in a relative form, e.g `~/test.conf` or `../test.conf`, but i can't get a proper full file path, though i've tried it with old `java.io` and new `java.nio Files/Paths`. Is there a general way to get a resolved file path without large amount of code? It would be fine for the solution to work only in unix envs like OsX or Debian.

**Update**

With a provided argument like `~/test.conf`
in case of `getAbsolutePath` it returns a path with a prefixed current folder - `/Users/currentUser/Projects/Personal/TestProject/~/text.conf`. Canonical path returns the same.

Comment: _but i can't get a proper full file path_ Show us what you've done and how it didn't work.

Comment: The shell should be globbing those arguments before calling your program, what isn't working?

Comment: Does getAbsolutePath() of java.io.File work?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen which could resolve any path that i could provide ("~/...", "../../...", etc...) without much magic from my side

Comment: The shell does not resolve "~" - you must do it yourself.  Relative paths should work out of the box relative to the current working directory of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The hard bit here is dealing with POSIX home directories, and sure you deal with `~otheruser/dir/test.conf` too (if you want to do it properly).

Luckily that's covered in [How to handle ~ in file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163364/).

TL;DR - use something like:

```
path.replace("~/", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/");
```

Once you've done that, and as others have commented, you can just use standard `java.io` methods (including `getCanonicalPath()`).

Comment: Thanks, but i'm interested in general solution, which could handle even cases like `../../test.txt`

Comment: @4lex1v That case should be handled fine with `Path#normalize()`.

Comment: This is not necessary.  The shell will already expand the `~` to the absolute path of the current user's home directory.  Try `echo ~` to see.  And if the user quoted the `~` to stop the shell from expanding, it surely had a reason for it and the program has no business in attempting to expand it again.

Comment: This is necessary. There's no guarantee of a shell being used to invoke this class.

Comment: If the user is not using a shell, then probably for a good reason.  If your program gets passed the argument `path/to-*-my.file > /dev/null || echo "damn it!"`, would you also attempt to expand the globing expression?  Would you set `System.out` to a null stream?  If your program fails, would you make it print “damn it!” and exit successfully?  Frankly, I don't think this is a good way to build software.

Comment: @5gon12eder ~-resolving of arguments is not done generically by the shell. The individual commands handle this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Compile this `public final class Echo { public static void main(final String[] args) { for (final String a : args) { System.out.println(a); } } }` and try running `java -cp . Echo ~ ~root *.class`.  It will output the absolute path of your home directory, the home directory of root and `Echo.class` (alongside with any other `*.class` files in the current directory).  That is, at least using Bash.  Of course you can imagine other shells that do different things but what shell to use is the *user's* decision.  A program should behave agnostic to this.

Comment: Of course it will - that's how Bash works. But: there's no guarantee of a shell being used to invoke this class - hence this SO question (and, note, equivalent standard methods [in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) and [in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path)).