# Call bash function in Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I have been using Java with bash in order to make some things easier, some examples:

From the main class to call a subclass in order to use bash commands:

Main classs:

```
    //Checking if the server already has the user or not
    CheckUser checkUser = new CheckUser();
    int checuser= checkUser.CheckUserMethod(user);
    if( 1 != checuser) { // Yoda notation

        //Making the directory for the user
        File userDirectory = new File(this.directory);
        userDirectory.mkdir();
    }
```

The class that will call the ".sh" file:

```
public class CheckUser {

protected int CheckUserMethod(String user){
    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd ~/Final-Year-Spring/src/main/java/query && ./checkuser.sh " + user});
        BufferedReader srdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s =srdInput.readLine();
        if(s==null){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

The bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2237
if ! [ -z "$1" ]
then
  cd ~/Final-Year-Spring/maps/ && find "$1" -maxdepth 0 -type d -printf 1
fi
```

Now you have a context.

I am trying to call a bash file that will execute a ffmpeg command. For instance, the same command when I am using the terminal:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.75 -to 00:00:00.93 -i ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/datassets/Alex/check/5535415699068794046/00009.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.71 -to 00:00:01.82 -i ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/datassets/Alex/check/5535415699068794046/00009.mp4 ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/maps/output.mp4S
```

Also a screenshot with the command in the cli:

[image]

The result of the cli command:

[image]

Now I am trying to do the same thing for multiple videos using Java and Bash.

The class that will create the input and the time:

public String CreateNewVideoMethod(){

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

MainSearch mainSearch = new MainSearch(this.array, this.search);
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String, HashMap<Double,Double>>>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map = mainSearch.SearchInVideous();


HashMap<String,HashMap<String, HashMap<Double,Double>>> file = new HashMap<>();
file=map.get(this.array.get(1));

file.forEach((k,v)->{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(this.defaultpth);
    stringBuilder.append("/")
            .append(this.array.get(0))
            .append("/")
            .append(this.array.get(1))
            .append("/")
            .append(k)
            .append("/")
            .append("InfoVideo.txt");

    GetVideoPath getVideoPath = new GetVideoPath();
    String videoPath = getVideoPath.GetVideoPathMethod(stringBuilder);

    v.forEach((k1,v1)->{ // iterate though the words
        v1.forEach((k2,v2)->{ // iterate though the times

            String doubleAsStringForKey = String.valueOf(k2);
            String[] arr = doubleAsStringForKey.split("\\.");

            String doubleASStringForValue = String.valueOf(v2);
            String[] arr2 = doubleASStringForValue.split("\\.");

            if(k2>10){

                StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder1.append(" -ss ")
                        .append("00:00:")
                        .append(arr[0])
                        .append(".")
                        .append(arr[1])
                        .append(" -to ")
                        .append(" 00:00:")
                        .append(arr2[0])
                        .append(".")
                        .append(arr2[1])
                        .append(" -i ")
                        .append(videoPath);
                arrayList.add(String.valueOf(stringBuilder1));
            }
                else{

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder1.append(" -ss ")
                            .append("00:00:0")
                            .append(arr[0])
                            .append(".")
                            .append(arr[1])
                            .append(" -to ")
                            .append("00:00:0")
                            .append(arr2[0])
                            .append(".")
                            .append(arr2[1])
                            .append(" -i ")
                            .append(videoPath);
                    arrayList.add(String.valueOf(stringBuilder1));
                }

        });
    });

});

BashFIleForCreatingNewVideo bashFIleForCreatingNewVideo = new BashFIleForCreatingNewVideo();
bashFIleForCreatingNewVideo.BashFileForCreatingNewVideo(arrayList);
```

The class that must call the ".sh" file:

```
public class BashFIleForCreatingNewVideo {

    protected String BashFileForCreatingNewVideo(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
        try {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(String str : arrayList){
            stringBuilder.append(str);
        }
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/src/main/java/com/FinalYearProjectServer/Get_Requests/CreateNewVideo && ./createNewVideo.sh ", String.valueOf(stringBuilder), String.valueOf(arrayList.size()-1), "./maps/outputstream.mp4"});
        BufferedReader srdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s =srdInput.readLine();

        if(s==null){
            return "Error";
        }else {
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

The script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( "$@" )

echo "${arr[*]}"

ffmpeg "${arr[0]}" -filter_complex concat=n="${arr[1]}":v=1:a=1 "${arr[2]}"
```

What is passed to the script, small exaple, this is a string:

```
 -ss 00:00:00.75 -to 00:00:00.93 -i ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/datassets/Alex/check/5535415699068794046/00009.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.71 -to 00:00:01.82 -i ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/datassets/Alex/check/5535415699068794046/00009.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.09 -to 00:00:00.34 -i ~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/datassets/Alex/check/5535415699068794046/00027.mp4
```

The next parameter is the number of videos that must concatenate and the last parameter is where the output must be.

My problem is the Bash file is not executing even the echo command or doing something. Do you have any suggestion, because I thing is about the way of how I am passing the array to the Bash file.

Ok so I am trying to use ProcessBuilder:

```
        String[] command = {"bash","ffmpeg", String.valueOf(stringBuilder), "-filter_complex concat=n="+String.valueOf(arrayList.size()-1)+":v=1:a=1", "~/IdeaProjects/Final-Year-Spring/maps/output1.mp4"};
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process p2 = p.start();
        BufferedReader srdInput;
        srdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
        String s =srdInput.readLine();
```

Comment: Have you checked if the script is executable? Insdead of doing "cd <path> && exec". just execute the script with the absolute path

Comment: Yes the script is executable.

Comment: You should really be using `ProcessBuilder`, which makes it a lot easier to handle stdout and stderr (call `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()` at first). Failing to handle them properly might cause processes to lock

Comment: *What is passed to the script, small exaple:* There are 18 arguments there. Your script only deals with a small fraction of those ..?

Comment: @g00se let me edit the question

Comment: Executing `"script " + argumentString` through a shell opens you up to serious security problems. Either pass your arguments as execv array entries or environment variables. See https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection for high-level background.

Comment: And using `bash -c` _with an argv_ means you have to know what you're doing -- if extra arguments aren't referred to from the argument directly following `-c`, they'll just be ignored completely. In general, the better answer is _don't_. You can tell ProcessBuilder to change directories; you don't need a parent shell to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, you can execute `ffmpeg` directly with `ProcessBuilder`. No need for the interpreter

Comment: Ok I will try to execute it there then

Comment: @g00se ok I edited the question to showcase if it is ok how I am using the ProcessBuilder, is it ok?

Comment: No, it's not. Don't run `bash ffmpeg`, just run `ffmpeg`. And each argument should be a separate array element.

Comment: That is to say, `-filter_complex` is one argument, `concat=n=...something...:v=1:a=1` is another argument, etc. The arguments themselves don't have any spaces -- the spaces are shell syntax, and if you do this right there is no shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok I am trying right now!

Comment: As you're still learning, I'll mention another thing to learn is how to debug by eliminating unneeded steps. Focus your search to the minimal code that causes the problem. Read [mcve]. Many times reducing your problem to something that doesn't require a TLDR will help you find your error and allow you to move forward faster. Good advice above, and pluse-uno to you because you're improving your question as you get feedback. Good luck.

Comment: Another note, looking at the current state of the code: `~` is a shell expansion. When you don't have a shell, it doesn't get replaced with a real name itself. See the related preexisting question [How to handle `~` in file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163364/how-to-handle-in-file-paths)

Comment: and btw, I looked at the ProcessBuilder docs, and it looks like it's just [`.directory(dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) to tell a ProcessBuilder which directory to run a program in.

Comment: Yes, list each argument on one line. As @CharlesDuffy said, each argument should be one element of the array. Start off with `ProcessBuilder.interitIO()` as I said earlier

Comment: BTW, one thing you can do is take your working shell command line, and run it with `printf ' %s\n'` in front; that'll print each argument on a separate line, with any expansions the shell performs (like `~`) already done; so you can see by where the line boundaries are where the array boundaries need to be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ".directory(dir) command can work if I have to work only in 1 directory. In this case, unfortunately, I have to get parts of multiple videos from different folders.

Comment: Your `bash -c` also has only one directory. How is calling `directory()` in ProcessBuilder different?

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your application, but as this question relates to course work I'm only leaving suggestions to help you understand what is wrong with all the command lines you have setup, and leave you to fix it.

I am going to run commands using `ProcessBuilder` as defined in [start() method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75843148/runtime-exec-freezes-on-execution-of-ffmpeg-audio-replacing-command-that-works/75843278#75843278). Note that I call `waitFor` to see what the result code is, and you can capture stdout/stderr by passing in `new ByteArrayOutputStream()` instead of `System.out/err`.

Consider this script saved as `bin/test.sh` of the current directory that you run `java` from:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo CMD:  $0
echo ARGS: $@
echo ARG1: $1
echo ARG2: $2
echo ARG3: $3
echo pwd   $(pwd)
echo SHELL $SHELL
```

The punctuation for any command needs to be exact. Launch the script as you've done with "bash+cd+&&+ someshell somearg","otherargs" as above shows first error - you've not joined up the command line arguments properly:

```
start(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd bin && ./test.sh 1","2", "3"}, null, System.out, null);

CMD: ./test.sh
ARGS: 1
ARG1: 1
ARG2:
ARG3:
```

As you can see, args "2" and "3" are NOT passed to the script "test.sh". You should have only used a 3 parameter `String[]`, the third parameter should be single value for the full command you want bash to run:

```
start(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd bin && ./test.sh 1 2 3"}, null, System.out, null);
CMD: ./test.sh
ARGS: 1 2 3
ARG1: 1
ARG2: 2
ARG3: 3
```

BUT: the first line of test.sh `#!/bin/bash` tells the OS all it needs to know about running `test.sh`, so you can use the command directly and just separate out the arguments properly:

```
start(new String[]{"bin/test.sh", "1","2","3"}, null, System.out, null);
CMD: bin/test.sh
ARGS: 1 2 3
ARG1: 1
ARG2: 2
ARG3: 3
```

If you need to change the current working directory of a command you should call `ProcessBuilder.directory(File cwd)` before `ProcessBuilder.start()`.

`ffmpeg` is a process you can launch directly, not necessary via `bash`. Just call it with every separated parameter (you don't). You will need to define each pair of multiple "-flag" and "value" as separate values in the argument list before passing on to `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList{}();
args.add("/absolute/path/to/ffmpeg"");

// LOOP over the other parameters {
    args.add("-ss");
    args.add("00:00:00.75");
}

args.add("-filter_complex");
args.add(filterValue);

... etc
```